# Desktop Neo4j Error: Cannot create property 'transport-class' on number '0'

Tags: heroku, neo4j

I have spined a Neo4j instance in Heroku and created a DB with few Nodes and relationships but when I tried to connect the same graph from the Neo4j desktop browser with below steps

Step 1: created a project

Step 2: Add the Remote Graph and enter the bolt and user name password

Step 3 : I have successfully connected to the Graph and showing all the count of Nodes and relationships I have created.

But here is the problem when I execute any query it pops below ERROR and I didn't find any solution from the net I think now one faced this issue :(

**ERROR:  Cannot create property 'transport-class' on number '78'**

[image]

Comment: In neo browser, navigate to Cloud services on the left, then "Clear local data". This worked for me, recently changed connection url so guess something was cached!

Answer (score 2):

I was also having the same issue. You need to update server connection using `:server connect` command and provide the connect url as `bolt://YOUR_SERVER_IP:7687` Your user name and password will be same as you have set it. This is working for me..!!

Comment: In my case, http specifically did not work, while bolt did :(